# Automating Price Updates in Magento After Migrating from WordPress

Tags: magento2

Hello Magento Community,

We're in the process of migrating our online store from WordPress to Magento and facing a unique challenge. Our business model involves highly volatile prices, which require frequent updates. To manage this, we have an automated system that generates a CSV file with updated prices every hour.

We're looking for advice or solutions on how to integrate this system with Magento. Specifically, we need Magento to automatically update product prices based on the hourly CSV file.

Has anyone implemented a similar price update mechanism in Magento? Any insights on plugins, custom scripts, or Magento settings that can facilitate this automated price update process would be incredibly helpful.

Thank you for your guidance!

Comment: 'Custom script is better or custom module"

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can do it with a small (self-coded) module with a cronjob.

Here is a tutorial, on how to create a module and create a cronjob:
https://magefan.com/blog/create-custom-cron-job-in-magento-2

The newly created cronjob needs to read the file (done with the class `Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File`) and update the prices for your products (loaded with the class `Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface`)

The `Magento\Framework\File\Csv` class is for reading the csv data in your file.

Here is an example where I assumed, your skus are in the first row and the prices are in the second row (not tested):

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Cron;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\File\Csv;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File as FileDriver;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class PriceUpdate
{
    /** @var Csv */
    protected $csvProcessor;

    /** @var LoggerInterface */
    protected $logger;

    /** @var ProductRepositoryInterface */
    protected $productRepository;

    /** @var FileDriver */
    protected $fileDriver;
    
    /**
     * Method __construct
     *
     * @param Csv $csvProcessor
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     * @param FileDriver $fileDriver
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(
        Csv $csvProcessor,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        FileDriver $fileDriver
    ) {
        $this->csvProcessor = $csvProcessor;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->fileDriver = $fileDriver;
    }

    /**
     * Method execute cronjob for priceupdate by csv file
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $filePath = '/var/productprice.csv'; // Set your actual file path
        if (!$this->fileDriver->isExists($filePath)) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__("File not found: %1", $filePath));
        }

        $data = $this->csvProcessor->getData($filePath);

        if (!is_array($data) || empty($data)) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__("CSV file is empty or invalid"));
        }

        foreach ($data as $row) {
            $sku = isset($row[0]) ? $row[0] : null; // Assuming SKU is in the first column
            $newPrice = isset($row[1]) ? $row[1] : null; // Assuming new price is in the second column

            if ($sku && $newPrice) {
                try {
                    $product = $this->productRepository->get($sku);

                    // Update product price
                    $product->setPrice($newPrice);
                    $product->save();

                    $this->logger->info("Price updated for product with SKU $sku. New price: $newPrice");
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    $this->logger->error("Error updating price for product with SKU $sku: " . $e->getMessage());

                }
            }
            $this->logger->info("Product prices updated successfully.");
        }
    }
}
```

You may also need to re-index the prices, to show them in frontend. But that would convolute the example code a bit.

If you have too many products, you can use the iterator class (`Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\IteratorFactory`), to prevent timeouts.
Feel free to ask, if you have more questions.